# How to get rid of \r \n and <br /> elements in a string

Tags: python, json

I've web scraped addresses and the address strings have unwanted elements like "\n" and "<br/>", how do I remove them?

```
Rosemount Viaduct,<br />\r\nAberdeen<br />\r\n
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to specify in your request that you want JSON, because none of that should appear in a JSON response.

Comment: @chepner If you look at the result, it *is* JSON. It just has this HTML in some of the strings.

Comment: I suspect that API is getting its data by scraping another website, and it's not cleaning the HTML before returning it.

Comment: Use the information in the `geolocation` properties, it seems to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean these html leftovers with a regular expression:

```
    import re

    value = "Rosemount Viaduct,<br />\r\nAberdeen<br />\r\n"
    clean_value = re.sub(r'\<br\s\/\>\r\n', r'', value)
```